# CSS Marquee Compatibility

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, marquee

I can't seem to find anywhere online the browser compatibility for the CSS Marquee properties. Can someone give me some information about which browsers (and versions) it works on.

P.s. I know some will say not to use marquees,  but it's a requirement for one of our clients. And I'd rather use CSS properties than Javascript or the  tag.

Here's the W3.org page on it. http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-marquee/#the-marquee-style

EDIT (08/10/203): Since this question, I have been experimenting and noticed that you can simulate a Marquee using CSS animation keyframes. Support is greater.

Comment: WebKit seem to have the chance to support it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions#Proprietary_WebKit-prefixed_properties_(do_not_use_on_Web_sites) but you'd better go for JS for compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, CSS3 Marquee is only supported in Webkit browsers (Chrome and Safari).

Notice that the only extension name available for the marquee element is [**-webkit-marquee**](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-webkit-marquee) (there isn't a `-moz-`, `-o-`, `-ms-` or 'general' marquee equivalent).

The status of Marquee implementation in Firefox [**is still unconfirmed**](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=648744) currently, and I can't find any information on plans to implement it in IE or Opera as of yet.

Comment: I think OP is talking about CSS3 marquee style, not HTML marquee element.

Comment: @Passerby Haha yep you're correct (haven't had my coffee this morning yet :D), updated.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I guess I'll stick to Javascript!