# Text rolling up in a Div

Tags: html, marquee

I need to display three lines of text in a DIV which has room for only one line.

I want the DIV to roll through the three lines and delay on each line for a few seconds.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are you doing now?

Comment: Look for a JavaScript scroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript to animate as described [here](http://remysharp.com/2008/09/10/the-silky-smooth-marquee/), for instance. There is also [marquee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_element) HTML element and it is [possible with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787859/css-marquee-compatibility?rq=1) but these alternatives are less consistently available between various browsers.